# Удалить последнюю строку в df Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

Приведенная ниже функция должна преобразовывать таблицу согласно выбранным значениям в визуальных элементах приложения Shiny и на последней итерации удалять нижнею строку т.к там получаются значения "NA", но почему то строка не удаляется. Не могу понять почему.

```
function(Selected_of_Store, Selected_of_Item, First_Date, Second_Date) 
{
    x <- filter (TestData, Store == Selected_of_Store, Item == Selected_of_Item);
    x <- summarise(group_by(x, Date, Item), Qty=sum(Qty));
    x <- left_join(Calendar, x, by = "Date");
    x <- filter (x, Date >=First_Date & Date <=Second_Date);
    x_melt <- melt(x, id = c("Date", "Item"));
    x_cast <- dcast(x_melt, ... ~ Date);
    x_final <- x_cast[, -c(2)];
    x_final <- df(x_final);
    x_final <- x_final(-nrow(x_final),);
    return(x_final)

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решилась путем перезаписывания строки по удалению последней строки следующим образом.

```
 x_final <- x_final[-c(nrow(x_final)),]
```